# The path of light relative to different observers

Tags: special-relativity, photons

Suppose that a laser pointer is fixed relative to the observer/frame $f'$. In the images A and B the laser and $f'$ are moving with linear constant velocity $\vec{V}$ relative to the fixed  frame $f$ and in images C and D the laser and $f'$ are rotating around the illustrated axis with constant angular momentum $\vec{L}$ relative to the fixed frame $f$. If the laser emits a single photon, do the  following images show its path relative to different observers correctly?

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A and B are right, but C and D are the wrong way around. A single photon will travel in a straight line in an inertial reference frame, so from the perspective of the person rotating with the laser, the photon will appear to be spiralling outwards.

Comment: I do not get your sentence: "A single photon will travel in a straight line in an internal reference frame". It seems to be inconsistent with "so from the perspective of the person rotating with the laser, the photon will appear to be spiralling outwards." Would you please explain more?

Comment: I think if the observer f' is in a closed container, it do not know that it is rotating or moving relative to the frame f. In other words, I think the conditions in the images A and C are identical relative to f' so the path of photon should be identical for f' in A and C.

Comment: No, the rotating frame is not inertial, so light will not follow a straight path in that frame.

Comment: Can't we assume that the $f'$ is fixed and $f$ is rotating? Then $f$ is not inertial.

Comment: Acceleration, unlike velocity, can be measured absolutely. When f' rotates, it is no longer inertial- that is why light does not then follow a straight path in f'.

Comment: So in your answer you have mistyped "internal reference frame" but you meant "inertial reference frame".

Comment: A thousand apologies- I have corrected the typo!